# Facebook like error - disabled/not visible

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

We've got a number of content managed sites that use the same functionality. We added a site recently, and the Facebook like button is failing with an error on-click (following Facebook login):

> This page is either disabled or not visible to the current user.

This only happens when the Facebook user isn't an administrator of the page, or of an application we've created for the page.

The site where this is failing is here: http://beachhousemilfordonsea.co.uk/

An example of a site that works (same code): http://monmouthash.co.uk/

The Facebook like code:

```
<fb:like href="http://beachhousemilfordonsea.co.uk/" width="380"></fb:like>
```

**Actions already taken**

I've checked with the FB Linter and there are a couple of Opengraph warnings that do need to be fixed (add a description, increase the image size) - but these are the same for all sites so should be affecting this (it's on the dev plan to get these rectified in the next release).

I've taken a look at the Facebook App we've got running on the problem page, and checked it against other working applications and the settings are the same as far as I can see, except there are missing options with this new application:

- Encrypted access token (assume this is default, not changeable now)
- Include recent activity stories

It doesn't feel like the application should have much of an impact on this though, as we use the application for the other functionality within the page (which is all working fine!).

I've searched for possible issues, and checked the more common ones:

- There are no age/geographic restrictions
- I've submitted 2 requests to Facebook in case the content is blocked, but no response or change

Any recommendations as to what else to try?

Thanks in advance,
Kev

P.S. I asked this question a week ago but it wasn't well formed - hopefully this is a better attempt, but if you need anything else please do let me know.

Comment: I was only allowed to add 2 links - here's the link to Facebook blocked content requests: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=244560538958131